# SpeechSynthesis: Lang vs Voice

Tags: javascript, browser, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

The [`SpeechSynthesisUtterance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance) interface provides two options for setting what voice gets used: `voice` and `lang`.

`lang` takes a language code like `en-US` or `es-ES`.

`voice` takes in a `SpeechSynthesisVoice` object that you get from `speechSynthesis.getVoices()`.

If both are unset, then the browser's default is used. If `lang` is unset, it just uses the `voice` provided. If `voice` is unset, it finds a `SpeechSynthesisVoice` that matches `lang`.

If both are set, but differ in what voice gets played. The `lang` setting seems to be the overriding factor.

Do I need to have both set? Will something go wrong if I only set the `voice` setting?

Comment: Is the behaviour not proving constant when you set `none`, `one` or `both`?

Comment: Behaviour is constant so far. But I guess I'm wondering why they have `lang` and `voice` when `voice` encompasses `lang`

Comment: It gives you the choice as to whether to define a specific synthesis voice service, or simply use the language tag, if you're not interested in the voices that are available.